# Google OAuth client is using the wrong project_id from the json file- Python

Tags: python, json, api, google-oauth, google-photos-api

My Python (3.6.7) code uses oauth2client to access Google Photos APIs. It successfully authenticates, but when it tries to access the Google Photos albums, it seems to be using the username as the project_id.

```
from __future__ import print_function
from apiclient.discovery import build
from httplib2 import Http
from oauth2client import file, client, tools

# Setup the Photo v1 API
SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/photoslibrary.readonly'
store = file.Storage('credentials.json')
creds = store.get()
if not creds or creds.invalid:
    flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('scripts/client_id.json', SCOPES)
    creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
service = build('photoslibrary', 'v1', http=creds.authorize(Http()))

# Call the Photo v1 API
results = service.albums().list(
    pageSize=10, fields="nextPageToken,albums(id,title)").execute()
items = results.get('albums', [])
if not items:
    print('No albums found.')
else:
    print('Albums:')
    for item in items:
        print('{0} ({1})'.format(item['title'].encode('utf8'), item['id']))
```

When executing the above code, it prompts me the auth page. When I successfully authenticate, it shows me the following error:

> HttpError 403 when requesting {URL} returned "Photos Library API has not been used in project **123456** before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/photoslibrary.googleapis.com/overview?project=**123456** then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.">

Interestingly, the number in bold **123456** (obviously changed) is actually the first part of the client_id found in the client_id.json

But the project_id looks something like this: **test1-235515**

So what I got from this error is that the oauth2client client is passing the client_id instead of the project_id. So even though I have enabled the Photos API, it will never access it correctly.

Please help with this error. How can I manually change the project_id?

Answer (score 0):

The project ID is different from the project number. You will be able to see both in your Google Cloud Console configuration. See this documentation for more on how to identify your projects [1].

A single Google Cloud project can have many different OAuth client IDs configured. See this documentation for information about creating OAuth client credentials [2]. You should be only have to make sure that the client you created belongs to the project for which you have enabled APIs. Going to the URL provided in the error message should take you to the right configuration page.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects#identifying_projects

[2] https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6158849?hl=en